# ¿ Por qué no funcionan las aplicaciones en la tableta?

Tags: css, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy empezando  a crear aplicaciones móviles con Cordova, para Android. Tengo pequeñas pruebas realizadas con la ayuda de compañeros 
de esta comunidad.
Pero el problema es que trate de correrlas en la tableta y  en la interfaz solo se ve una pequeña muestra de 
del contenido. Hace la función, pero va bastante mas despacio que en el móvil.
Imagino que la clave estará en css.
Mi pregunta es, ¿ si debo añadir algún plugin, configurar css de alguna manera determinada, o algún otro archivo debo de 
hacerle algo ? ¿ Que necesito para que funcionen en tabletas y teléfonos ?
Quizá no me explico muy bien o no doy datos concretos, pero no se me ocurre, dejo muestra del código por si vale de algo.
Un saludo y muchas gracias

```js
window.onload = alert("Hola...! disfruta de mi juego \nHaz clic en 'INICIAR', entonces debes colocar la imagen ... \nAsí que haz clic en la imagen...");

//establecemos el tiempo y los movimientos

var steps = 0;
var sec = "00";
var min = 0;
var seconds;
var minuts;
var div_sec = document.getElementById('sec');
var div_min = document.getElementById('min');
var classNames = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight'];
function startTimer() {
    seconds = setInterval(secTimer, 1000); minuts = setInterval(minTimer, 60000);
}
function secTimer() {
    sec++;

    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    else if (sec > 59) {
        sec = "0" + 0;
    }
    div_sec.innerHTML = sec;
}
function minTimer() {
    min++;
    div_min.innerHTML = min;
}

function clearTimer() {
    clearInterval(seconds);
    clearInterval(minuts);

}
function resetTimer() {
    sec = "00";
    min = 0;
    div_sec.innerHTML = sec;
    div_min.innerHTML = min;
}


//cambiando la imagen

var numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("box");


function change(x, left, up, right, down, left2, up2, right2, down2) {
    var id = x;
    if (left == true && verIfEmpty(id - 1) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id, id - 1);

    }
    else if (left2 == true && verIfEmpty(id - 2) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id - 1, id - 2);
        changeContent(id, id - 1);

    }
    else if (up == true && verIfEmpty(id - 3) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id, id - 3);

    }
    else if (up2 == true && verIfEmpty(id - 6) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id - 3, id - 6);
        changeContent(id, id - 3);

    }
    else if (right == true && verIfEmpty(id + 1) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id, id + 1);

    }
    else if (right2 == true && verIfEmpty(id + 2) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id + 1, id + 2);
        changeContent(id, id + 1);

    }
    else if (down == true && verIfEmpty(id + 3) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id, id + 3);

    }
    else if (down2 == true && verIfEmpty(id + 6) == true) {
        steps++;
        changeContent(id + 3, id + 6);
        changeContent(id, id + 3);

    }
}

function verIfEmpty(x) {
    var a = document.getElementById(x);
    var c = a.innerHTML;
    if (c === "") {
        y = true;
    } else {
        y = false;
    }
    return y;
}

//Esta parte funciona gracias a Asier Villanueva

function changeContent(x, y) {
    var m = document.getElementById(x);
    var n = document.getElementById(y);
    n.innerHTML = m.innerHTML;
    n.className = m.className;
    m.innerHTML = "";
    m.className = "";
    win();
    showScore();
    ok();
}

//este generador aleatorio que encontré en internet


function randomGenerator(low, high) {
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
        high = low;
        low = 0;
    }
    this.low = low;
    this.high = high;
    this.reset();
}

randomGenerator.prototype = {
    reset: function () {
        this.remaining = [];
        for (var i = this.low; i <= this.high; i++) {
            this.remaining.push(i);
        }
    },
    get: function () {
        if (!this.remaining.length) {
            this.reset();
        }
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.remaining.length);
        var val = this.remaining[index];
        this.remaining.splice(index, 1);
        return val;
    }
}

//escribe los números al azar en el rompecabezas
//Esta parte funciona gracias a Asier Villanueva

function getNum() {
    var randomNoRepeatNumbers = new randomGenerator(0, 8);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        var newNumbers = document.getElementById(i);
        var rndNumber = randomNoRepeatNumbers.get();
        newNumbers.innerHTML = rndNumber;
        newNumbers.className = "box " + classNames[rndNumber - 1];
    }
    for (var i in numbers) {
        if (numbers[i].innerHTML == 0) {
            numbers[i].innerHTML = "";
            numbers[i].className = "";
        }
    }
    steps = 0;
    showScore();
    verifArray();
    clearTimer();
    resetTimer();
    startTimer();
    ok();
}



function win() {

    var time = min + ":" + sec;
    var win = true;
    for (var i in numbers) {
        if (numbers[i].innerHTML != numbers[i].id) {
            if (numbers[i].id != numbers.length) {
                win = false; break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (win) {
        clearTimer();
        function showAlert() {
            alert("Has ganado...!!! \nUsted hizo" + steps + "movimientos \nTu tiempo a sido " + min + " min. y " + sec + " sec.");
        }
        setTimeout(showAlert, 1000);

        //Modify the code with the help of @Asier Villanueva and it works perfectly

        var celda9 = document.getElementById('9');
        celda9.innerHTML = "9";
        celda9.className = "box nine";

    }
}

function showScore() {
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = ("MOVES = " + steps);
}

function verifArray() {
    var count = 0;
    var arrayNum = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        var w = document.getElementById(i).innerHTML;
        arrayNum[i] = w;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= arrayNum.length - 1; i++) {
        for (var n = i + 1; n <= arrayNum.length - 1; n++) {
            if (arrayNum[i] > arrayNum[n] && arrayNum[n] != 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count % 2 != 0) {
        getNum();
    }
}

function ok() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        var x = document.getElementById(i);
        if (x.innerHTML == i) {
            x.style.color = "#74a57a";
        } else {
            x.style.color = "#ffffff";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .main {
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  body {
    background: grey;
  }
  
  h1,
  p {
    font-family: open sans;
    margin: 5px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 95%;
  }
  
  .board {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 90%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px black inset;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .box {
    position: absolute;
    height: 33.33%;
    width: 33.33%;
    float: left;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-image: url("http://i64.tinypic.com/21l6gck.jpg");
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px black;
    background-size: 300%;
  }
  
  .border {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  
  div.one {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
  }
  
  div.two {
    background-position: -100% 0%;
  }
  
  div.three {
    background-position: -200% 0%
  }
  
  div.four {
    background-position: 0% -100%
  }
  
  div.five {
    background-position: -100% -100%;
  }
  
  div.six {
    background-position: -200% -100%;
  }
  
  div.seven {
    background-position: 0% -200%;
  }
  
  div.eight {
    background-position: -100% -200%;
  }
  
  div.nine {
    background-position: -200% -200%;
  }

  #music{
    display: none; 
    autoplay: true;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
       <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">-->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <nav>
              <div id="score">Movimientos = 0</div>
              <div class="time" id="sec">00</div>
              <div class="time">:</div>
              <div class="time" id="min">0</div>
              <div class="time">TIEMPO = &nbsp; </div>
              <div id="start">
                <span onclick="getNum()">INICIAR </span>
              </div>        
            </nav>       
            <div class="main">
              <div class="board" id="board">
                <div class="box one" id="1" onclick="change(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1)" style="top:0%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>
                <div class="box two" id="2" onclick="change(2,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1)" style="top:0%;left:33.33%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>
                <div class="box three" id="3" onclick="change(3,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1)" style="top:0%;left:66.66%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>
                <div class="box four" id="4" onclick="change(4,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0)" style="top:33.33%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>
                <div class="box five" id="5" onclick="change(5,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)" style="top:33.33%;left:33.33%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>
                <div class="box six" id="6" onclick="change(6,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0)" style="top:33.33%;left:66.66%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>
                <div class="box seven" id="7" onclick="change(7,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0)" style="top:66.66%;left:0%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                                 
                <div class="box eight" id="8" onclick="change(8,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="top:66.66%;left:33.33%;"><div class="border"> </div></div>                              
                <div class="box nine" id="9" onclick="change(9,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)" style="top:66.66%;left:66.66%;"><div class="border"> </div> </div>                               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <img src="img\bob-patricio.jpg">
        <iframe src="audio\BobEsponjaRemix.mp3" id="music"></iframe> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No veo ningun error. Lo que pasa es que tienes que utilizas [medias query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) para poder aplicar los estilos en base a la resolucion de la pantalla.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Einer, la verdad es que estube estudiando la documentacion del link, pero no me a quedado muy claro.                                       Volvere a estudiarlo a ver si entiendo la manera.   Gracias por el apoyo